# Displaying an Ember handlebars template within a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Here is a Rails view that I'm working with:

```
<%= current_user.name %>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="my-template">
    {{view App.ColumnView}}
  </script>
</div>
```

When the page renders, I expected the template rendered by `App.ColumnView` to display within the row-fluid div. Instead, it renders outside of my application layout's `yield` statement. Here is my application layout (omitted `<html>` block:

```
<body class="container">
  <header id="page-header">
    <h1>App</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

My page ends up rendering like this:

```
<body class="container">
  <header id="page-header">
    <h1>App</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <div id="ember259" class="ember-view">
     ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Seems like ember is appending the view to the `<body>` tag instead of rendering inside of my Rails view. Is there a way to render it inline with my Rails views?

Comment: Did you try setting the `rootElement` of the application? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html

Comment: @edpaez that worked, would you mind creating an answer so I can accept? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rootElement` property of the Ember application defaults to `body`, so Ember appends everything there.

You can of course, specify the element in which all of your application will be displayed

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#ember-app'
});
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement

I'm glad this helped you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, was having exactly the same problem!